# How to set the default value group select in angular material

Tags: angular, select, angular-material

I am trying to get set a default value for the material.io form but I cant seem to get it working with the groups version.  Here is my code

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Pokemon" [formControl]="pokemonControl">
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
                  [disabled]="group.disabled">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
        {{ pokemon.viewValue }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>



selected = 'bulbasaur-0';

  pokemonGroups = [
    {
      name: 'Grass',
      pokemon: [
        { value: 'bulbasaur-0', viewValue: 'Bulbasaur' },
        { value: 'oddish-1', viewValue: 'Oddish' },
        { value: 'bellsprout-2', viewValue: 'Bellsprout' }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Psychic',
      pokemon: [
        { value: 'mew-9', viewValue: 'Mew' },
        { value: 'mewtwo-10', viewValue: 'Mewtwo' },
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

To set an option as selected, your select model must cope with the desired option.

Since you use reactive forms, try creating it like this :

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  pokemonControl: this.pokemonGroups[0][0]
});
```

If you don't use a reactive form, then use this

```
pokemonControl: new FormControl(this.pokemonGroups[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comparison function.
Angular does not simply know how to select it. Accordingly to documentation **compareWith** - *Function to compare the option values with the selected values. The first argument is a value from an option. The second is a value from the selection. A boolean should be returned.* [docs link](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

So regarding your implementation
**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Pokemon" [formControl]="pokemonControl" [compareWith]="compareWith">
     <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
     <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
                              [disabled]="group.disabled">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
                    {{pokemon.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pokemonControl.setValue(this.selected);
  }

compareWith = (a: unknown, b: unknown): boolean => {
    return a == b;
  };
```

PS. In case your option value is an object then you can simply create a more complex comparator to display values.

*IN YOUR CASE*: To compare such complex objects with array types I would implement a life hack solution by stringifying the object. Simple and efficient.

```
compareWith = (a: YourType, b: YourType): boolean => {
    if (!a || !b) return false;
    return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution to your question.

The [Angular Select documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value) use two-way binding for `value` attribute for  simple `mat-select` and `mat-option` ...
But with `mat-optgroup` is not working, so you would better use [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) binding.

**HTML:**

```
**<**mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Pokemon" [formControl]="pokemonControl" [(ngModel)]="selected">
   <mat-option>-- None --</mat-option>
     <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of pokemonGroups" [label]="group.name"
                              [disabled]="group.disabled">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let pokemon of group.pokemon" [value]="pokemon.value">
                    {{pokemon.viewValue}}
       </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS:**

```
selected: string = 'squirtle-3';
```

**UPDATE:**

The above will be working for Angular 6, and you will give a warning.

> It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as
>   formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and
>   ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated
>   in Angular v6 and will be removed in Angular v7.

So you should use `FormControl` and use `setValue` [link](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue) method in your case:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.pokemonControl.setValue(this.selected);
  }
```